# text overlapping at start of pdf when table row exceeds the length of the page

Tags: php, dompdf

I am attaching the pdf1.php which contain the code for rendering the data to a pdf. Data is represented in tables dynamically through database. Since the data is dynamic the table rows may extend to a new page which leads to the overlapping of text at the start of the pdf. I tried placing the table row in a div but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciable.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
include('../DBConnect.php');
session_start();
$year=$_SESSION['pbasYear'];
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

//Select query for general information
$sqlgen="SELECT * from gen_info where user_id='$user'";
                $genresult=mysqli_query($con,$sqlgen) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));
                $genrow=mysqli_fetch_array($genresult);
                $name=$genrow['Gen_Info_Name'];
                $fname=$genrow['Gen_Info_Fname'];
                $mname=$genrow['Gen_Info_Mname'];
               $dept=$genrow['Gen_Info_Department'];
                $cd=$genrow['Gen_Info_CD'];
                $gp=$genrow['Gen_Info_GP'];
                $dlp=$genrow['Gen_Info_DLP'];
                $afc=$genrow['Gen_Info_AFC'];
                $pa=$genrow['Gen_Info_PA'];
                $tno=$genrow['Gen_Info_TNO'];
                $email=$genrow['Gen_Info_Email'];

//Select query for academic activity
$sqlacad="SELECT * FROM acad_act where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $acadresult = mysqli_query($con,$sqlacad) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));
                $acresult = mysqli_query($con,$sqlacad) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));
                $acrw=mysqli_fetch_array($acresult);

                if($acrw>0)
                {

                    $acno="Yes";

                }
                else
                {
                    $acno="No";
                }   

//Select query for Lectures, Seminar,Tutorial, Practical, Contact Hours
$sqllstp="SELECT * from teach_lstp where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $lstpresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqllstp) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));
                $lstpapi=mysqli_fetch_array($lstpresult);

//Select query for Reading/Instructional material consulted and additional knowledge resources provided to students

$sqlrimc="SELECT * from teach_rimc where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $rimcresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlrimc) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


//Select query for Use of Participatory and innovative Teaching-Learning Methodologies, Updating of subject contents

$sqltlm="SELECT * from teach_tlm where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $tlmresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqltlm) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));

//Select query for  Examination Duties Assigned and Performed 

$sqledap="SELECT * from teach_edap where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $edapresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqledap) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


 //Select query for (i) Extension, Co-curricular & Field based activities.

$sqlecfa="SELECT * from teach_ecfa where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $ecfaresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlecfa) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


//Select query for Contribution to Corporate Life and Management of the Institution.

$sqlclmi="SELECT * from teach_clmi where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $clmiresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlclmi) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


//Select query for Professional Development Activities.

$sqlpda="SELECT * from teach_pda where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $pdaresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlpda) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


//Select query for Published Papers in Journals.

$sqlppij="SELECT * from teach_ppij where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $ppijresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlppij) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


//Select query for Articles/ Chapters published in Books.                 

$sqlapb="SELECT * from teach_apb where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $apbresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlapb) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


//Select query for Full papers in Conference Proceedings. 

$sqlfcp="SELECT * from teach_fcp where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $fcpresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlfcp) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));



// Select query for Books published as single author or as editor. 

$sqlbpe="SELECT * from teach_bpe where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $bperesult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlbpe) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


// Select query for Ongoing Projects/ Consultancies.

$sqlopc="SELECT * from teach_opc where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $opcresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlopc) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


// Select query for Completed Projects/ Consultancies.

$sqlcpc="SELECT * from teach_cpc where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $cpcresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlcpc) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


// Select query for Completed Projects/ Consultancies.

$sqlrg="SELECT * from teach_rg where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $rgresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlrg) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


// Select query for Training Courses, Teaching-Learning-Evaluation Technology, Faculty Development Programmes

$sqlfdp="SELECT * from teach_fdp where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $fdpresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlfdp) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


// Select query for  Papers presented in Conferences, Seminars, Workshops, Symposia

$sqlppc="SELECT * from teach_ppc where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $ppcresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlppc) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));


//Select query for Invited Lectures and Chairmanship at National or International Conference/ Seminar

$sqlilc="SELECT * from teach_ilc where user_id='$user' and year='$year'";
                $ilcresult=mysqli_query($con , $sqlilc) or die('Error'.mysqli_error($con));



//Calculation of Summary of API.


            $get1 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_LSTP_CTAPI) as value_sum  from Teach_LSTP where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
                  $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get1); 
                  $lstp1 = $row1['value_sum'];

                  $get2 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_LSTP_TLAPI) as value_sum  from Teach_LSTP where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
                  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get2); 
                  $lstp2 = $row2['value_sum'];

                  $lstp=$lstp1+$lstp2;


                  $get3 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_TLM_API) as value_sum  from Teach_TLM where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
                  $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get3); 
                  $tlm = $row3['value_sum'];


                  $get4 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_EDAP_API) as value_sum  from Teach_EDAP where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
                  $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get4); 
                  $edap = $row4['value_sum'];


                  $teachinglearning=$lstp+$tlm+$edap;


            $get5 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_ECFA_API) as value_sum  from Teach_ECFA where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
            $row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get5); 
            $ecfa = $row5['value_sum'];

            $get6 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_CLMI_API) as value_sum  from Teach_CLMI where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
            $row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get6); 
            $clmi = $row6['value_sum'];

            $get7 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_PDA_API) as value_sum  from Teach_PDA where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
            $row7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get7); 
            $pda = $row7['value_sum'];

            $CoCurricular=$ecfa+$clmi+$pda;

        $sum=$teachinglearning+$CoCurricular;

        $get8 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_PPIJ_API) as value_sum  from Teach_PPIJ where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row8 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get8); 
        $ppij = $row8['value_sum']; 

        $get9 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_APB_API) as value_sum  from Teach_APB where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row9 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get9); 
        $apb = $row9['value_sum'];  

        $get10 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_FCP_API) as value_sum  from Teach_FCP where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row10 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get10); 
        $fcp = $row10['value_sum']; 

        $get11 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_BPE_API) as value_sum  from Teach_BPE where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get11); 
        $bpe= $row11['value_sum'];  

        $get12 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_OPC_API) as value_sum  from Teach_OPC where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row12 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get12); 
        $opc = $row12['value_sum']; 

        $get13 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_CPC_API) as value_sum  from Teach_CPC where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row13 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get13); 
        $cpc = $row13['value_sum']; 

        $get14 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_RG_API) as value_sum  from Teach_RG where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row14 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get14); 
        $rg = $row14['value_sum'];  

        $get15 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_FDP_API) as value_sum  from Teach_FDP where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row15 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get15); 
        $fdp = $row15['value_sum']; 

        $get16 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_PPC_API) as value_sum  from Teach_PPC where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row16 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get16); 
        $ppc = $row16['value_sum']; 

        $get17 = mysqli_query($con, "select sum(Teach_ILC_API) as value_sum  from Teach_ILC where user_id='$user' and year='$year'");
        $row17 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get17); 
        $ilc = $row17['value_sum']; 

        $research=$ppij+$apb+$fcp+$bpe+$opc+$cpc+$rg+$fdp+$ppc+$ilc;                


 /*General Information Table */
  $html =
    '<html><body>'.
    '<h3><center>University of Indore</center></h3><br/>'.
    '<h3><center>Devi Ahilya University, Indore</center></h3><br/>'.
    '<h4><center>Annual Self-Assessment for the Performance Based Appraisal System (PBAS)</center></h4><br/>'.
    '<h4><center>Session/Year :'.$year.' </center></h4><br/>'.
    '<h3><center>PART A : GENERAL INFORMATION</center></h3><br/>'.
    '<table border="1px" width="100%"><tr><th>Name</th><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Father`s Name</th><td>'.$fname.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Mother`s Name</th><td>'.$mname.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Department</th><td>'.$dept.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Current Designation</th><td>'.$cd.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Grade Pay</th><td>'.$gp.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Date of Last Promotion</th><td>'.$dlp.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Address for Correspondance</th><td>'.$afc.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Permanent Address</th><td>'.$pa.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Contact No.</th><td>'.$tno.'</td></tr>'.
    '<tr><th>Email</th><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>'.
    '</table>';

/*Academic activity table    */

    $acrow = mysqli_fetch_array($acresult);
    $html.=

    '<br><B>Whether acquired any degree or fresh academic qualification during the year : '.$acrow['Gen_Info_AQ'].''.
    '<br><B>Whether acquired any degree or fresh academic qualification during the year: '.$acno.''.
    '<br><table width="100%" border="1px">'.
    '<tr><th>Name of Course</th><th>Place</th><th>Duration</th><th>Sponsoring Agency</th></tr>';
   while($acadrow = mysqli_fetch_array($acadresult)){
    $html .='<tr><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_Noc'].'</th><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_Place'].'</th><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_Duration'].'</th><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_SA'].'</th></tr>';}

    $html.='</table><br/><h3><b><center>PART B : ACADEMIC PERFORMACE INDICATORS</center></b></h3><br/>'.


/*CATEGORY  I : TEACHING LEARNING AND EVALUATION RELATED ACTIVITES*/

/*LSTP Table*/    

    '<h3><center><b>CATEGORY  I : TEACHING LEARNING AND EVALUATION RELATED ACTIVITES</b> </center></h3><br/>'.
    '<h4>(i) Lecture, Seminar, Tutorial, Practical, Contact Hours (Semester Wise)</h4>'.
    '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
    '<tr><th>Course/Paper</th><th>Level</th><th>Mode of Teaching</th> <th>No. of classes/per week allocated</th> <th>Total no. of classes conducted</th> <th>Practicals</th> <th>% of classes taken as per documented record</th></tr>';
    while($lstprow=mysqli_fetch_array($lstpresult)){
    $html .='<tr><td>'.$lstprow['Teach_LSTP_Course'].'</td> <td>'.$lstprow['Teach_LSTP_Level'].'</td><td>'.$lstprow['Teach_LSTP_MOT'].'</td><td>'.$lstprow['Teach_LSTP_NOCA'].'</td> <td>'.$lstprow['Teach_LSTP_NOCC'].'</td> <td>'.$lstprow['Teach_LSTP_Practicals'].'</td> <td>'.$lstprow['Teach_LSTP_CTDR'].'</td></tr> ';}

    $html .='</table><br/><b><h4>Lecture (L), Seminars (S), Tutorials (T), Practical (P), Contact Hours (C)</h4></b>'.
        '<table border="1px" width="100%">'.
        '<tr><th></th> <th></th> <th>API Score</th></tr>'.
        '<tr><th>(a)</th><th>Classes Taken (max 50 for 100% performance & Proportionate Score upto 80% performance, below which no score may be given) </th><td>'.$lstpapi['Teach_LSTP_CTAPI'].'</td></tr>'.
        '<tr><th>(b)</th><th>Teaching Load in excess of UGC norm (max score:10)</th><td>'.$lstpapi['Teach_LSTP_TLAPI'].'</td></tr>'.

/*RIMC Table*/

        '</table><br/><h4>(ii) Reading/Instructional material consulted and additional knowledge resources provided to students :</h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Course Paper</th><th>Consulted </th><th>Prescribed</th> <th>Additional Resources Provided</th></tr>';
        while($rimcrow = mysqli_fetch_array($rimcresult)){
        $html .='<tr><th>'.$rimcrow['Teach_RIMC_Course'].'</th><th>'.$rimcrow['Teach_RIMC_Consulted'].'</th><th>'.$rimcrow['Teach_RIMC_Prescribed'].'</th><th>'.$rimcrow['Teach_RIMC_ARP'].'</th></tr>';}

/*TLM Table*/

        $html.='</table><br/><h4>(iii) Use of Participatory and innovative Teaching-Learning Methodologies, Updating of subject contents :</h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Short Description</th><th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($tlmrow = mysqli_fetch_array($tlmresult)){
        $html .='<tr><th>'.$tlmrow['Teach_TLM_SD'].'</th><th>'.$tlmrow['Teach_TLM_API'].'</th></tr>';}

/*EDAP Table*/ 

        $html.='</table><br/><h4>(iv) Examination Duties Assigned and Performed </h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Type of Examination duties</th><th>Duties Assigned</th><th>Extent to which carried out(%) </th><th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($edaprow = mysqli_fetch_array($edapresult)){
        $html .='<tr><th>'.$edaprow['Teach_EDAP_TED'].'</th><th>'.$edaprow['Teach_EDAP_DA'].'</th><th>'.$edaprow['Teach_EDAP_ECO'].'</th><th>'.$edaprow['Teach_EDAP_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*CATEGORY  II : CO-CURRICULAR, EXTENSION, PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPMENT  RELATED  ACTIVITIES */
        $html.='</table><br/><h3><center><b>CATEGORY  II : CO-CURRICULAR, EXTENSION, PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPMENT  RELATED  ACTIVITIES </b> </center></h3><br/>'.


/*ECFA Table*/

        '<br/><h4>(i) Extension, Co-curricular & Field based activities </h4><br/>'.

        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Type of Activity</th><th>Average Hrs per Week</th><th>API Score</th></tr>';

        while($ecfarow = mysqli_fetch_array($ecfaresult)){
        $html .='<tr><th>'.$ecfarow['Teach_ECFA_TOA'].'</th><th>'.$ecfarow['Teach_ECFA_AH'].'</th><th>'.$ecfarow['Teach_ECFA_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*CLMI Table*/

        $html.='</table><br/><h4>(ii) Contribution to Corporate Life and Management of the Institution </h4><br/>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Type of Activity</th><th>Yearly/Semester wise responsibility</th><th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($clmirow = mysqli_fetch_array($clmiresult)){
        $html .='<tr><th>'.$clmirow['Teach_CLMI_TOA'].'</th><th>'.$clmirow['Teach_CLMI_YSR'].'</th><th>'.$clmirow['Teach_CLMI_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*PDA Table*/

        $html.='</table><br/><h4>(iii) Professional Development Activities</h4><br/>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Type of Activity</th><th>Yearly/Semester wise responsibility</th><th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($pdarow = mysqli_fetch_array($pdaresult)){
        $html .='<tr><th>'.$pdarow['Teach_PDA_TOA'].'</th><th>'.$pdarow['Teach_PDA_YWR'].'</th><th>'.$pdarow['Teach_PDA_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*CATEGORY   III : RESEARCH, PUBLICATION AND ACADEMIC CONTRIBUTION*/


        $html.='</table><br/><br/><h3><center><b>CATEGORY   III : RESEARCH, PUBLICATION AND ACADEMIC CONTRIBUTION</b> </center></h3><br/>'.

/*PPIJ Table*/

        '<br/><h4>A) Published Papers in Journals</h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title with page no.</th><th>Journal</th><th>ISSN/ISBN No.</th> <th>Whether peer reviewed.Impact factor,if any</th> <th>No. of Co.authors</th> <th>Whether you are the main author</th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($ppijrow = mysqli_fetch_array($ppijresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$ppijrow['Teach_PPIJ_TNO'].'</th><th>'.$ppijrow['Teach_PPIJ_Journal'].'</th> <th>'.$ppijrow['Teach_PPIJ_ISBN'].'</th> <th>'.$ppijrow['Teach_PPIJ_PR'].'</th> <th>'.$ppijrow['Teach_PPIJ_NCA'].'</th> <th>'.$ppijrow['Teach_PPIJ_MA'].'</th>  <th>'.$ppijrow['Teach_PPIJ_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*APB Table*/

        $html.='</table>'.
        '<br/><h4>B (i) Articles/ Chapters published in Books.</h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title with page no.</th><th>Book Title,editor & publisher</th><th>ISSN/ISBN No.</th> <th>Whether peer reviewed.Impact factor,if any</th> <th>No. of Co.authors</th> <th>Whether you are the main author</th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($apbrow=mysqli_fetch_array($apbresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$apbrow['Teach_APB_TNO'].'</th> <th>'.$apbrow['Teach_APB_BEP'].'</th> <th>'.$apbrow['Teach_APB_ISSN'].'</th> <th>'.$apbrow['Teach_APB_WPR'].'</th> <th>'.$apbrow['Teach_APB_NOC'].'</th> <th>'.$apbrow['Teach_APB_MA'].'</th> <th>'.$apbrow['Teach_APB_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*FCP Table*/

       $html.='</table>'.
        '<br/><h4>B(ii) Full papers in Conference Proceedings.</h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title with page no.</th><th>Details of Conference publication</th><th>ISSN/ISBN No.</th> <th>No. of Co.authors</th> <th>Whether you are the main author</th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($fcprow=mysqli_fetch_array($fcpresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$fcprow['Teach_FCP_TNO'].'</th> <th>'.$fcprow['Teach_FCP_BEP'].'</th> <th>'.$fcprow['Teach_FCP_ISSN'].'</th> <th>'.$fcprow['Teach_FCP_NOC'].'</th> <th>'.$fcprow['Teach_FCP_MA'].'</th> <th>'.$fcprow['Teach_FCP_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*BPE Table*/

        $html.='</table>'.
        '<br/><h4>B (iii) Books published as single author or as editor. </h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title with page no.</th><th>Type of Book & Authorship</th><th>Publisher & ISSN/ISBN No.</th> <th>Whether peer reviewed</th> <th>No. of Co.authors</th> <th>Whether you are the main author</th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($bperow=mysqli_fetch_array($bperesult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$bperow['Teach_BPE_TPN'].'</th> <th>'.$bperow['Teach_BPE_TBA'].'</th> <th>'.$bperow['Teach_BPE_PISSN'].'</th> <th>'.$bperow['Teach_BPE_WPR'].'</th> <th>'.$bperow['Teach_BPE_NOC'].'</th> <th>'.$bperow['Teach_BPE_MA'].'</th> <th>'.$bperow['Teach_BPE_API'].'</th></tr>';}      

/*OPC Table*/

        $html.='</table><br/><h4>C) Ongoing and Completed Research projects and consultancies</h4>'.
        '<h4>Ongoing Projects/ Consultancies.<br/></h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title </th><th>Agency</th><th>Period</th> <th>Grant/Amount Mobilized(Rs. Lakh)</th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($opcrow=mysqli_fetch_array($opcresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$opcrow['Teach_OPC_Title'].'</th> <th>'.$opcrow['Teach_OPC_Agency'].'</th> <th>'.$opcrow['Teach_OPC_Period'].'</th> <th>'.$opcrow['Teach_OPC_GAM'].'</th> <th>'.$opcrow['Teach_OPC_API'].'</th></tr>';}      


/*CPC Table*/

        $html.='</table><br/>'.
        '<h4>Completed Projects/ Consultancies.<br/></h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title </th><th>Agency</th><th>Period</th> <th>Grant/Amount Mobilized(Rs. Lakh)</th> <th> Whether policy document/Patent as outcome </th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($cpcrow=mysqli_fetch_array($cpcresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$cpcrow['Teach_CPC_Title'].'</th> <th>'.$cpcrow['Teach_CPC_Agency'].'</th> <th>'.$cpcrow['Teach_CPC_Period'].'</th> <th>'.$cpcrow['Teach_CPC_GAM'].'</th> <th>'.$cpcrow['Teach_CPC_WPD'].'</th> <th>'.$cpcrow['Teach_CPC_API'].'</th></tr>';}      



/*RG Table*/

        $html.='</table>'.
        '<br/><h4>Research Guidance.<br/></h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Number Enrolled </th><th>Thesis Submitted</th><th>Degree Awarded</th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($rgrow=mysqli_fetch_array($rgresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$rgrow['Teach_RG_NE'].'</th> <th>'.$rgrow['Teach_RG_TS'].'</th> <th>'.$rgrow['Teach_RG_DA'].'</th> <th>'.$rgrow['Teach_RG_API'].'</th></tr>';}      


/*FDP Table*/

        $html.='</table>'.
        '<br/><h4>E (i) Training Courses, Teaching-Learning-Evaluation Technology, Faculty Development Programmes.<br/></h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Programme </th><th>Duration</th><th>Organized By</th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($fdprow=mysqli_fetch_array($fdpresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$fdprow['Teach_FDP_Programme'].'</th> <th>'.$fdprow['Teach_FDP_Duration'].'</th> <th>'.$fdprow['Teach_FDP_Organized'].'</th> <th>'.$fdprow['Teach_FDP_API'].'</th></tr>';}      


/*PPC Table*/

        $html.='</table>'.
        '<br/><h4>E (ii) Papers presented in Conferences, Seminars, Workshops, Symposia.<br/></h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title of paper presented </th><th>Title of Conference/Seminar etc.</th><th>Date of the event</th> <th> Organized By </th> <th> Whether International/National/State </th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($ppcrow=mysqli_fetch_array($ppcresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$ppcrow['Teach_PPC_TPP'].'</th> <th>'.$ppcrow['Teach_PPC_TCS'].'</th> <th>'.$ppcrow['Teach_PPC_DOE'].'</th> <th>'.$ppcrow['Teach_PPC_Organized'].'</th> <th>'.$ppcrow['Teach_PPC_WINS'].'</th> <th>'.$ppcrow['Teach_PPC_API'].'</th></tr>';}      


/*ILC Table*/

        $html.='</table>'.
        '<br/><h4>E(iii) Invited Lectures and Chairmanship at National or International Conference/ Seminar.<br/></h4>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr><th>Title of the Lecture/Academic Session </th><th>Title of Conference/Seminar etc.</th><th>Date of the event</th> <th> Organized By </th> <th> Whether International/National/State </th> <th>API Score</th></tr>';
        while($ilcrow=mysqli_fetch_array($ilcresult)){
        $html.='<tr><th>'.$ilcrow['Teach_ILC_TOL'].'</th> <th>'.$ilcrow['Teach_ILC_TCS'].'</th> <th>'.$ilcrow['Teach_ILC_DOE'].'</th> <th>'.$ilcrow['Teach_ILC_Organized'].'</th> <th>'.$ilcrow['Teach_ILC_WINS'].'</th> <th>'.$ilcrow['Teach_ILC_API'].'</th></tr>';}      
        $html.='</table><br/><br/>'.


/*Table of API summary */

        '<h3>IV. SUMMARY OF API SCORES</h3>'.
        '<table width="100%" border="1px">'.
        '<tr align="center"><th> </th><th>Criteria</th><th>Last Academic Year</th> <th> Total API Score for Assessment Period</th> <th>Annual Average API Score for Assessment Period </th></tr>'.
        '<tr align="center"><td> I </td> <td> TEACHING LEARNING AND EVALUATION RELATED ACTIVITIES</td><td> </td><td>'.$teachinglearning.' </td><td> </td></tr>'.
        '<tr align="center"><td>II</td><td>CO-CURRICULAR,EXTENSION PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPMENT RELATED ACTIVITIES</td><td> </td><td>'.$CoCurricular.' </td> <td> </td></tr>'.
        '<tr align="center"><td> </td> <td>TOTAL I + II </td> <td> </td><td>'.$sum.' </td><td> </td></tr>'.
        '<tr align="center"><td> III</td> <td> RESEARCH,PUBLICATION AND ACADEMIC CONTRIBUTION</td> <td> </td> <td>'.$research.' </td> <td> </td></tr>'.
        '</table> <br/><br/>'.
        '<h3><center>PART C: OTHER RELEVANT INFORMATION</center></h3> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>'.


/*Footer Detail*/


        '<h4>I certify that the information provided is correct as per records available with the University and/or documents enclosed along with the duly filled PBAS proforma. </h4>'.
        '<br/><div align="right"><h4>Signature of the faculty</h4>'.
        '<h4>Designation : '.$cd.'</h4>'.
        '<h4>Place : Indore</h4>'.
        '<h4>Date : '.Date("d/m/Y").'</h4><br/><br/><br/>'.
        '<h4>Signature of HOD</h4></div>'.
        '</body></html>'; 





$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("PBAS.pdf");

?>
```

Comment: FYI for future issues: with dompdf problems it helps more to see the HTML you're trying to render, rather than the PHP that produces the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're probably running into a syntactical error in your HTML. I didn't go through the whole code, but the following would definitely cause an issue:

```
/*Academic activity table    */

$acrow = mysqli_fetch_array($acresult);
$html.=

'<br><B>Whether acquired any degree or fresh academic qualification during the year : '.$acrow['Gen_Info_AQ'].''.
'<br><B>Whether acquired any degree or fresh academic qualification during the year: '.$acno.''.
'<br><table width="100%" border="1px">'.
'<tr><th>Name of Course</th><th>Place</th><th>Duration</th><th>Sponsoring Agency</th></tr>';
while($acadrow = mysqli_fetch_array($acadresult)){
$html .='<tr><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_Noc'].'</th><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_Place'].'</th><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_Duration'].'</th><th>'.$acadrow['Gen_Info_SA'].'</th></tr>';}

$html.='</table><br/><h3><b><center>PART B : ACADEMIC PERFORMACE INDICATORS</center></b></h3><br/>'.
```

The `<B>` is not closed, which essentially places a non-inline object (your table) inside an inline object. Browsers have evolved to the point where they can easily handle issues like this. dompdf can handle this but it depends on what release you're using and your configuration.

v0.6.0 includes a HTML5 parser that helps resolve syntax issues before anything else happens. I've found more often than not this prevent problems caused by syntax errors. I'd recommend using v0.6.0 with the HTML5 parser enabled. If that's not possible then at the very least you should run the HTML through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org) and address any issues.